# change local data object on change of global state

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to edit and update using vuex. I have two components, one is form for entry/edit and another for viewing data. When I click on edit button of view component I want to populate the form component with the data from backend.

Note that I already have a data object on form component that is bind with form and used to store data. I want to change it on edit. I have no problem on getting data from backend.

**I just can not change the local data object from state**

This is my codes what I've tried

*Form component:*

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            form:{
                id:'',
                name:'',
                email:'',
                phone:'',
                address:''
            }
        }
    },
    computed:{
        ...mapState({
            data (state) {
                this.form=state.employee; //This is where I am stuck
            }
         }),

    }
```

*state:*

```
export default{
    state:{
        employee:{}
    },
    getters:{}
    },
    mutations:{
        setEmployee(state,employee){
            state.employee=employee;
        }
    },
    actions:{
        fetchEmployee({commit},id){
            axios.put('employee-edit/'+id)
            .then(res=>res.data)
            .then(employee=>{
                commit('setEmployee',employee)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

*view component:*

```
export default {
    methods:{
        editEmployee(id){
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchEmployee',id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you  want to use `get` instead of `put`? Are you getting data (`employee`) after resolving `res.data` from the response?

Comment: yes I am getting data as expected

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues/misunderstandings with your approach.

1) `computed` properties are "passive" and supposed to `return` a value "computed" from other values. Directly assigning to your local state is probably not what you want to do.

2) HTTP methods: `In general the HTTP PUT method replaces the resource at the current URL with the resource contained within the request.`
Please read up on http methods and how they are supposed to be used. You want `GET`

3) `mapState` is a helper method if you need multiple getters from vuex state store. I suggest you use `this.$store.getters.myVariableInState` for simple tasks like in your example.

What you probably want is more along these lines:

```
// store
getters:{
  employee: state => state.employee
}

// component
computed: {
  employee() {
    return this.$store.getters.employee
  }
}
```

If your actions was already dispatched earlier and the data is available in the store all you then need is

```
methods: {
  editEmployee() {
    this.form = this.employee
  }
}
```

Since your question stated "change local data on state change", here is an approach for that:
`watch` your local computed property

```
watch: {
  employee() {
    // this.employee (the computed value) now refers to the new data 
    // and this method is triggered whenever state.employee changes
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but your mentioned `editEmployee()` method is not called from anywhere because the edit button is in a separate component. 
In my code editEmployee method used to fetch data directly from backend.

Comment: @MoshiurRahman don't you need the employee data anyways to display before editing? I would dispatch the `fetchEmployee` action in a `created` hook of one of the components and then have your edit button emit an `edit` event that you can listen to and call the `editEmployee()` method. Other solution (but not as clean) would be to use the watcher as described above and simple call `this.editEmployee()` from the watcher.